# Is is possible in regex to allow float numbers between 0 and 2?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, numbers

I need to validate text input through regex expression. Text input only accept float numbers between 0 and 2 else it through validation error. Currently I'm using this expression

```
^\d+\.\d{0,2}$
```

But it only validates on numbers (1.0, 2.0...). Following are the valid/invalid input for text.

**Valid:**

- 0
- 1
- 2
- 0.1
- 1.9
- 2.0
- 0.01
- 1.09
- 1.009

**Invalid:**

- -1
- 3
- 2.1
- 2.01
- 2.001

Comment: When regex is your hammer, everything looks like a thumb. Why not just convert to a float and do a numerical compare?

Comment: Why not parse it using `parseFloat()` and then use `<=` and `>=`. Would look like: `let num = parseFloat(str); let check = isNaN(num) && num>=0 && num<=2;`

Comment: Try `^(?:[01](?:\.\d+)?|2(?:\.0+)?)$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9DzBQK/1)

Comment: Is it possible to write a regular expression to match pi? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `^\d+.\d{0,2}$` accepts 1+ digits from 0-9 at the start using `\d+`, so you should limit that to 0 or 1 using a character class.

If you don't intend to match a digit followed by a single dot, you could turn this part `.\d{0,2}` into `\d+` so values like  `1.` or `0.` are not valid.

You can do that using an alternation:

```
^(?:[01](?:\.\d+)?|2(?:\.0+)?)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9DzBQK/1/)

```js
let pattern = /^(?:[01](?:\.\d+)?|2(?:\.0+)?)$/;
["0", "1", "2", "0.1", "1.9", "2.0", "0.01", "1.09", "1.009",
  "0.", "1.", "-1", "3", "2.1", "2.01", "2.001"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + (pattern.test(s) ? " = ok" : " = not ok")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```js
var regex = /^([01](\.[0-9]+)?|2(\.0+)?)$/;

var tests = [
  "0", "1", "2", "0.1", "1.9", "2.0", "0.01", "1.09", "1.009",
  "-1", "3", "2.1", "2.01", "2.001", "1.", "2."
];
tests.forEach(function(str) {
  console.log(str + " " + (regex.test(str) ? "pass" : "fail"));
});

document.querySelector("#input1").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = regex.test(this.value) ? "#6F6" : "#F66";
});
```

```html
<input id="input1" placeholder="Enter a number">
```

Comment: Just replace `*` with `+` (although `2.` should be valid).

Comment: @junaid see revised answer.